# Why is that there is no tangent law?

Tags: trigonometry

We know that, in a triangle ABC, sine law and cosine law are well developed formulas.

My questions are:-

1. Why is that there is no tangent law? (If no, just hope that someone can devise one someday.)
2. Can the identities like $\tan A  + \tan B + \tan C = \tan A\tan B\tan C$ be qualified?

2'. If it does not qualify, is it because it (1) is too difficult to use; or (2) has no practical value wrt applications; or (3) has no sides involved.

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents

Comment: Glad to know that. But that was seldom heard and practically rare to see any application of it.

Comment: Just divide sin and cos in respective laws... what do you get?

Comment: The law of tangents is equivalent to either the law of sines or the law of tangents, making the law of tangents a superfluous result in terms of theory. Historically, its usefulness derived from the fact that for some problems the law of tangents would result in a smaller loss of significant digits when using tables of values to find numerical approximations of trig functions. With the invention of modern calculators though, we stopped needing to worry about that, and so the law of tangents fell out of use.

Comment: For all values of X, it is very weird to asky why there is no X when there is even a Wikipedia page on X. You should really try the obvious places before asking!

Answer (score 1):

There is a law called as [tangent law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents) $$\color{red}{\text{But the thing is all these results are equivalent.}}$$ If you want you can deduced cosine rule from sin rule.
Also if you want you can deduced sine rule from cosine rule.
As I think using one of theses rules and the relation $A+B+C=\pi$ we can solve any triangle.